# Keeping secrets in Azure Function Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions

This article:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/change-config-azure-webapps

discusses using the Powershell Set-AzureWebsite command to "change the appSettings and connectionStrings values in the Web.config file"

Is this applicable to Azure Functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are based on the same platform, so this works identically. e.g. if you set an Azure App Setting called `FOO`, you will have an environment variable called `FOO` that you can consume in your Function logic.

Or if using C#, you can also write `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FOO"]`.

Comment: I am using C# but I didn't understand your "Or if using C# you can also write" statement.  Also as opposed to what alternative?

Comment: As opposed to the option described in the first paragraph: read it as a straight environment variable without going through config system.